# Using Generics to retrieve a list of classes of type Generic

Tags: java, generics

I'm relatively new to generics in Java, so I apologize if this is something common that gets taught in schools (I'm pretty much self-taught). Let's say I have the interface and abstract class below

```
public interface IChallenge<T> {
    boolean handle(T e);
    Class<? extends T> getType();
}
```

```
public abstract class AbstractChallenge<T> implements IChallenge<T> {
    protected Class<T> clazz;
    
    @Override
    public Class<? extends T> getType() {
        return this.clazz;
    }
}
```

For every class that extends AbstractChallenge, the `handle` method takes in the parameter that is specified for the generic. So if I had an event class that gets triggered when `Event` happens, I would have

```
public class EventChallenge extends AbstractChallenge<Event> {
    public EventChallenge() {
        super(Event.class);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handle(Event e) {}
}
```

My problem comes when I'm trying to pass a specific class to the `handle` method. Since the generic can be any class, and there can be multiple challenges with the same type, I have the challenges stored in a map with their type as the key.

`private Map<Something, List<AbstractChallenge<Something>> challenges = new HashMap<>();`

With the ultimate hope of achieving something along the lines of

```
List<AbstractChallenge<A>> specificChallenges = this.challenges.get(A.class);
specificChallenges.removeIf(challenge -> challenge.handle(A));
```

But I'm having a hard time figuring out what goes in the 'Something'. If I put the wildcard `?` symbol, then IntelliJ says that `handle` must take in a parameter of the requirement: capture of ? when I pass it class A. The best I've gotten to is to not specify the type for `AbstractChallenge` but I'd like a better solution.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want the class as a key for the map and not the object. So this should work private `Map<Class<?>, List<IChallenge<?>> challenges = new HashMap<>();`. Also notice that I changed the list type from `AbstractChallenge` to `IChallenge`. It's always nicer to work with the interface and not the abstract implementation.

Comment: So you want to: 1. Get all 'challenge' classes that handle a specific type. 2. From that list, remove any 'challenge' that successfully handled an event?

Comment: @markspace Yes! I have the removing-the-challenge-if-completed correctly figured out, but haven't figured out how to get the list of challenges with the specified type. I'll re-edit my post to make this more clear.

Comment: @magicmn I initially tried that (although with AbstractChallenge instead of IChallenge), and IntelliJ says

```Required type: List<IChallenge<Event>>
Provided: List<IChallenge<?>>```

For reference, this is the line

```List<IChallenge<Event>> list = this.challenges.get(Event.class)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you seek is something like that (I took the comment here):

```
private Map<Class<?>, List<IChallenge<?>> challenges = new HashMap<>();

A a = ...;
challenges.get(a.getClass())
          .removeIf(challenger -> challenger.handle(a));
```

This is unsafe as it can be and you can't do much because you don't know the actual type of T (the compiler does not, so the much it can do is infer it, and in this case, the type would be `Object`):

- The key can be any type, for example `Integer.class`
- The value can be any type `IChallenge<T>` and if `T` is not `Integer` (or `Number`, `Object`, eg: any type in the hierarchy of `T`), it may fail if the implementation use the object it handles and do some cast.

When you add:

```
challenges.get(Integer.class).add((Number a) -> a.intValue() > 10); // #1
challenges.get(Integer.class).add((Integer a) -> a.intValue() > 10); // #2
challenges.get(Integer.class).add((Object a) -> a != null); // #3
challenges.get(Integer.class).add((String a) -> a.length() > 10); // #4
```

Here is an example:

```
Integer a = Integer.valueOf(5);
// #1 -> ok: a is a Number
challenges.get(a.getClass()).removeIf(c -> c.handle(a));
// #2 -> ok: a is an Integer
challenges.get(a.getClass()).removeIf(c -> c.handle(a));
// #3 -> ok: a is an Object
challenges.get(a.getClass()).removeIf(c -> c.handle(a));
// #4 ->ko: a is not a String
challenges.get(a.getClass()).removeIf(c -> c.handle(a));
```

If you wish to avoid that, but still be able to handle anything challenge, you should ensure that the class holding/building the challenges do it correctly:

```
public <T> void addChallenge(Class<T> type, IChallenge<T> challenge) {
  challenges.computeIfAbsent(type, ignored -> new ArrayList<>()).add(challenge);
}
```

While you could use the `getType()` your defined in `IChallenge`, I wanted to show you how to enforce that the type (the key) and the `IChallenge` (the value) can be secured: normally, unless you gave write access to the map to other classes, this should be safe because the compiler validate the type at insertion.

Therefore, when you remove them, you should never have a `ClassCastException` due to the type parameter of `IChallenge`.

You could also try playing with `? super T` and `? extends T` but that's another challenge.

--

Regarding your comment:

> I'm not entirely sure how to go about using the addChallenge method you specified. Right now, I have a list of Class> for every challenge created, and when a specific challenge should be loaded, the program instantiates using .newInstance(). Should I be doing it differently? I only need a certain amount of challenges loaded at once, not all – DeprecatedFrank

I am not telling to load all challenges at once, I am merely telling your to use OOP to ensure that no one, but your challenge holder (let call it `ChallengeHolder`) manage the map, and manage it so that you avoid generics pitfall:

```
class ChallengeHolder {
  private final Map<Class<?>, List<IChallenge<?>>> challenges;
  public ChallengeHolder() {
    this.challenges = new HashMap<>();
  }

  public <T> void addChallenge(Class<T> type, IChallenge<T> challenge) {      
      challenges.computeIfAbsent(type, ignored -> new ArrayList<>()).add(challenge);
  }

  public boolean handle(Object a) {
    List<IChallenge<T>> challengers = challenges.get(a);
    if (challengers == null) return false;
    return challengers.removeIf(c -> c.handle(a));
  }   

}
```

Since there are no public access to challenges beyond what the `ChallengeHolder` class provides, there should be no problem with using `Object` or `Class<T>`.

If you need to create `IChallenge` on demand, then you could perhaps an implementation like this:

```
public class LazyChallenge<T> implements IChallenge<T> {
  private final Class<IChallenge<T>> impl;
  private IChallenge<T> value;

  public LazyChallenge(IChallenge<T> impl) {
    this.impl = impl;
  }

  public boolean handle(T o) {
    if (value == null) {
      try {
        value = impl.getConstructor().newInstance();
      } catch (java.lang.ReflectiveOperationException e) { // ... a bunch of exception your IDE will fill in ...
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
      }
    }
    return value.handle(o);
  }
}
```

You would then add it to `ChallengeHolder`:

```
challengeHolder.addChallenge(String.class, new LazyChallenge<>(StringChallenge.class));
```

Or you could use lambda to avoid the reflection:

```
public class LazyChallenge<T> implements IChallenge<T> {
  private final Class<IChallenge<T>> supplier;
  private IChallenge<T> value;

  public LazyChallenge(Supplier<IChallenge<T>> supplier) {
    this.supplier = supplier;
  }

  public boolean handle(T o) {
    if (value == null) {
      value = supplier.get();
    }
    return value.handle(o);
  }
}
```

And:

```
challengeHolder.addChallenge(String.class, new LazyChallenge<>(StringChallenge::new));
```

And after though, you may directly use `Supplier` in place of `IChallenge` in `ChallengeHolder`:

```
class ChallengeHolder {
  private final Map<Class<?>, List<Supplier<IChallenge<?>>>> challenges;
  public ChallengeHolder() {
    this.challenges = new HashMap<>();
  }

  public <T> void addChallenge(Class<T> type, Supplier<IChallenge<T>> challenge) {      
      challenges.computeIfAbsent(type, ignored -> new ArrayList<>()).add(challenge);
  }

  public boolean handle(Object a) {
    List<IChallenge<T>> challengers = challenges.get(a);
    if (challengers == null) return false;
    return challengers.removeIf(c -> c.get().handle(a));
  }   

}

StringChallenge existing = ... ;
// always reuse an existing
challengeHolder.addChallenge(String.class, () -> existing);
// bring a new challenge each time that ChallengeHolder::handle is called
challengeHolder.addChallenge(String.class, StringChallenge::new);
```

If I were to implements it, I would use the lambda way because you avoid reflection pitfalls (the try catch, the visibility problems especially given that Java 9++ introduced modules, ...).

The `LazyChallenge` defined above may help to avoid creating the `StringChallenge` more than one. In that case, it would be best to have it implements `Supplier<T>` instead of `IChallenge<T>`.

This whole digression does not change what I pointed out earlier: ensure that only `ChallengeHolder` read/write the map.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to go about using the `addChallenge` method you specified. Right now, I have a list of `Class<? extends IChallenge<?>>` for every challenge created, and when a specific challenge should be loaded, the program instantiates using `.newInstance()`. Should I be doing it differently? I only need a certain amount of challenges loaded at once, not all